# Union commands after the || (OR) operator

Tags: linux, command-line, test

When I write the code the way below, I am able to run several commands after the `else` statement:

```
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
    then              
        echo "OK"
    else 
        echo "NOK"
        exit 1
fi
```

However, when I use another syntax I am unable to union 2 commands after the **OR**:

```
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && echo "OK" || (echo "NOK" >&2 ; exit 1)
```

In my use-case I have a complex script based on `"$?" == 0`, so I'm looking for a way to abort (additionally to echoing the message) when it is not true.

Comment: Not that the question isn't a good one, but I'm curious why you are so insistent on avoiding the `if`/`then`/`else` syntax. If you're worried about having to use several lines, it is perfectly possible to make a one-liner of it: `if a; then b; else c; fi`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pair of `(` `)` spawns a subshell, defeating the goal of exiting the whole script with the exit command inside.

Just replace the `(` `)` with `{` `}`  (and adjusted syntax because `{` `}` are not automatical delimiters but more treated like commands: a space after `{` and last command inside must end with some terminator:`;` fits): this will run the chain of commands inside in the same shell, thus exit will affect this shell.

```
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && echo "OK" || { echo "NOK" >&2; exit 1;}
```

UPDATE: @D.BenKnoble commented that should `echo` fail, the behaviour won't be like the former `if ...; then ... else ... fi` construct. So the first `echo`'s exit code has to be "escaped" with a noop `:` command (which being built-in can't fail).

```
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && { echo "OK"; :;} || { echo "NOK" >&2; exit 1;}
```

references:

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01):

> Grouping Commands
>
> The format for grouping commands is as follows:
>
> ```
> (compound-list)
>      Execute compound-list in a subshell environment; see Shell
>      Execution Environment. Variable assignments and built-in commands 
>      that affect the environment shall not remain in effect
>      after the list finishes.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> { compound-list;}
>      Execute compound-list in the current process environment. The
>      semicolon shown here is an example of a control operator delimiting
>      the } reserved word. Other delimiters are possible, as shown
>      in Shell Grammar; a <newline> is frequently used.
> ```

[dash manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/dash/dash.1.en.html#Grouping_Commands_Together),[bash manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bash/bash.1.en.html#Compound_Commands),...

Comment: This is NOT guaranteed to work the way you think it will; if echo fails for some reason the script will exit.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you're right. I was just addressing the obvious, considering echo cannot fail.  Addressed it by forcing the exit code of the (now first) compound command.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use the following script line:

```
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && echo "OK" || exit $(echo "NOK" >&2 ; echo 1)
```

That serves the purpose of reporting an error and returning an error code, whilst being silent if the "OK" path is chosen.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are executing the other branch in a subshell (that is what the parentheses mead - e.g. in `bash(1)` man page look for `compound commands`) - thus the `exit` quits the subshell and not the shell executing the script. To see it more graphically, put a long enough `sleep` in both versions of your code, and run `ps faux` (for `coreutils` version of `ps`) or something like `pstree` to see the process ancestry relationships.

Now, how to "fix" it:

1. there's nothing wrong about `if ... then / else / fi`. Especially for longer blocks it makes the code more readable.
2. if you want a one liner, then you can do

   ```
   [ "$?" -eq 0 ] && echo "OK" || echo "NOK" >&2 && exit 1
   ```

   which relies on echo exiting gracefully, or use a group command

   ```
   [ "$?" -eq 0 ] && echo "OK" || { echo "NOK" >&2 ; exit 1; }
   ```

   Check for general availability in your shell and for any peculiarities though - e.g. it should be terminated by a newline or a semicolon.
3. most comprehensive - use a signal/event handler (`bash` example, syntax for other shells might differ):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   exit_handler () {
       echo "error happened, exiting"
       ... fix things, that may be half baked ...
   }

   trap exit_handler EXIT

   ... do stuff ...
   ```

   This gives you the opportunity to:

   - use `set -e` (`set -o errexit`) which is often considered dangerous - the `EXIT` handler can do things like removing any temporary files you one doesn't want to leave behind
   - have the cleanup code in one place only
   - handle other signals (those sent by e.g. `kill`) as well